# {modelsummary} showing and customizing FEs

Tags: r, modelsummary

In displaying fixed effects regressions from `fixest` with `modelsummary`, I want to remove the default stats of AIC and BIC, and keep only the FE variable and the sample size, in that order.

I don't know how to refer to the "FE:[Variable] X" stat in modelsummary. Is that a `gof` statistic? It doesn't show up in `modelsummary::gof_map`. I'd rather not use regex as in `gof_omit` since it is harder to teach.

Here I attempted `gof_map = c("nobs", "FE")` but that didn't work.

```r
library(modelsummary)
library(fixest)
library(readr)

url <- 'https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/csv/HistData/Guerry.csv'
dat <- read_csv(url)


# want to only keep FE and N, in that order
modelsummary(feols(Literacy ~ Wealth | Region, dat), 
             gof_map = c("FE", "nobs"), 
             output = "markdown")

#> NOTE: 1 observation removed because of NA values (Fixed-effects: 1).
```

|  | Model 1 |
| --- | --- |
| Wealth | -0.113 |
|  | (0.071) |
| Num.Obs. | 85 |

```r
# FE does not show up
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I recommend you use the `gof_omit` argument. Refer to the main documentation: https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/reference/modelsummary.html

Comment: You can also call `get_gof(model)` to extract a data frame with the "raw" names of each statistic, in the format they should appear if you want to use `gof_map`.

Comment: ok the second comment is what I was looking for.  I understand how to use `gof_omit`, but a `gof_include` will be easier to teach to my students.

Comment: The `gof_map` argument can be used as a `gof_include`, by supplying a character vector. Please see the latest documentation.

Comment: @Vincent I meant that `gof_omit` accepts regex but `gof_map` does not?  e.g. `gof_map = "FE"` will not retain all gofs that include the character "FE". I can open a issue.

Comment: By all means. But `gof_omit` accepts negative lookaheads, to *keep* statistics instead of omitting them. See the docs for `coef_omit`: https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/reference/modelsummary.html